# Will I have problems if I accept two job offers in two different EU countries?

Tags: contract-law, european-union, germany, france, visa

I am non-European and I have never lived in France. I recently got a job offer from a company in France and I signed it. A few weeks later, I received another job offer from a company in Germany.

Being non-European, there is a risk of not obtaining the necessary papers in France since it has to be proved that I am the best candidate on the market (ie. no other EU citizen is fit for the job). So I thought about signing the German offer as well in order to have a plan B if things do not work out with France.

My question is: by signing these two offers, will the two countries know that I have two ongoing visa/work-permit procedures at any given time? If yes, could this cause me problems?

Thank you

Comment: Hi Can u tell us what have u done in the end ?

Answer (score 3):

As far as your visa is concerned, both, France and Germany are in the Schengen area, so a visa in one of those countries will give you access to both.

As for as your work permit is concerned, at least in Germany you will need some participation of your new employer. They will have to prove that they can find nobody else in the EU. So they'll probably want you to sign the employment contract.

As far as getting out of such a contract in Germany, you have to differentiate between a fixed-term contract (e.g. for 2 years) and an indefinite contract. Once you sign a fixed-term contract, it is difficult to get out of it before its normal end. Unlimited contracts in Germany usually come with a 6 month probation period, where both, the employer and employee can end the contract immediately. In this specific case you might be able to get out of the German contract. I don't know though if the employer would go through the trouble of obtaining a work permit for you without binding you for a fixed amount of time to them.

Answer (score 0):

You are intending to be in breach of a contract. So not only a breach, but intentional. That will have legal consequences, and a company in Germany or France can reach you if you are in the EU, and sue for damages. There are other threads that indicate that in Germany, this will actually happen.

Consider that the company where you breach your contract will from now on assume that people from your home country are unreliable and cannot be trusted, based on costly experience, so you **** it up for everyone coming from your home country.

Comment: That is actually not a "problem". As an employee, you have a trial period (don't know the exact wording in English) where you and the employer try out each other. So I can always find a polite excuse for giving my resignation after working couple days.

Comment: My question is rather about the process of issuing visa + work permits, and if at any points there would be an intersection of both processes given that they are in EU

Comment: If you think it's not a problem, go ahead. Fact is: Germany and "polite excuse" doesn't mix well. There is a _very_ strong worth ethics there, and what you are planning to do will make them very angry. And if they are angry, and you are in France, they are going to find you. As I said, you are free to disagree and go ahead.